# CPT loop doesn't seem to account for post date?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, loop

I have some custom post types called "products", all with different published dates. Below is my loop that grabs these posts:

```
 $args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $numposts, 
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'product-category' => $cat,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'author' => $author,
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if (!$loop->have_posts()){
    return 'No products available.';
}
```

I have my orderby set to date desc, but it's not taking effect on the frontend (they're just randomly ordered). What's also odd is that in the backend, if I look at my custom posts and sort by the "date" column, they don't sort there either. It's like it can't read the published date even though the date is showing on each post. Thoughts?

Comment: Update - it appears my loop is using the "post modified" date as opposed to the "post published" date. How can I force my loop to use the published date?

Comment: can you include your post loop? It's not normal to see a negative check `have_posts` that returns. Also it would only use the post modified date if you had specified `modified` instead of `date` according to the documentation (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters), this implies that a `pre_get_posts` filter is interfering/modifying your query parameters